# Open source HTML5 JS library for flowchats

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, flowchart

I am planning to write an application that can allow me to draw flowchart like diagrams that can span over multiple dynamic rectangles (nodes) connected to N level of depth. Obvious  thought is to use a flowchat library to achieve the purpose. I like the examples give by http://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html but due to licensing terms I might not be able to use it.

I am searching for opensource JS library so I can draw such diagrams on HTML5 canvas. Any thoughts?

Comment: From the example you have given, I guess fabricjs can be a good choice. There's nothing flowchart specific features there, but I am sure you can easily adapt it to create something like that fabricjs.com

Comment: thanks will check this one too

Comment: Out of curiosity: What's wrong with the license terms of GOJS? What aspect of "Open Source" is it you are interested in? Price?

Comment: While we still do not have clarity on what kind of license we are going to procure (whether Evaluation, Internal Use & OEM license), we have gone through the Software License Agreement and following are our observations from legal perspective: 

1. Evaluation License can be used exclusively for the purpose of evaluation. Warranties mentioned in clause 3 of the agreement are not applicable to Evaluation License.

Comment: 2. Liability of Northwoods for any claim arising out of the delivery, use, performance, or non-performance of any licensed product is limited to US$ 10 only.

3. License contains sentence that - All software contains errors, and Customer acknowledges that the use of any software (including the Licensed Software) entails the likelihood of some human and machine errors, omissions, delays, interruptions, and losses, including inadvertent loss of data or damage to media, which may give rise to loss or damage.

Comment: you could always write your own:)

Comment: @ManishDevraj, if you're still looking for answers, i believe your question would be considered on-topic at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for something similar now. Have you found any good open-source libraries? I have posted my question here, can you please have look and provide some suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69885058/7584240

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found some nice library for something that matches our need. Anyone looking for similar ones check this out at GitHub https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb

Comment: Now here I think https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb

Comment: Please update the answer with the github link. The current is dead.

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for something similar now. Have you found any good open-source libraries? I have posted my question here, can you please have look and provide some suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69885058/7584240